# Loading local tokenizer

Tags: python, tokenize, bert-language-model, roberta-language-model

I'm trying to load a local tokenizer using;

```
from transformers import RobertaTokenizerFast

tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(r'file path\tokenizer')
```

however, this gives me the following error;

```
OSError: Can't load tokenizer for 'file path\tokenizer'. If you were trying to load it from 'https://huggingface.co/models', make sure you don't have a local directory with the same name. Otherwise, make sure 'file path\tokenizer' is the correct path to a directory containing all relevant files for a RobertaTokenizerFast tokenizer.
```

The file directory contains both a merges.txt and vocab.json file for the tokenizer, so I am not sure to how to resolve the issue.

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to point to the directory that contains those files, not one of those specific files. So get the path to that directory and define the `tokenizer` as you've done above, but with the path between `''` in place of `r'file path\tokenizer'`.

```
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('path_to_directory')
```

`RobertaTokenizerFast` expects to find `vocab.json`, `merges.txt`, and `tokenizer.json` in that directory, so make sure you have downloaded everything it requires. Note that you may also individually point to these files by passing the arguments `vocab_file`, `merges_file`, and `tokenizer_file`. See the [docs](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.29.1/en/model_doc/roberta#transformers.RobertaTokenizerFast) for further information.

Comment: Thanks, the path to the file directory is fine, however I only have vocab and merges files. These were the result of saving a ByteLevelBPETokenizer in an earlier step.
`from tokenizers import ByteLevelBPETokenizer
tokenizer = ByteLevelBPETokenizer()

tokenizer.train(files=paths, vocab_size=30_522, min_frequency=2,
               special_tokens=[
                   '<s>', '<pad>', '</s>', '<unk>', '<mask>'
               ])`

Comment: I think you may just need to point to the files directly then. `tokenizer = RobertaTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('path_to_directory/vocab.json', 'path_to_directory/merges.txt')`

Comment: Otherwise save the `ByteLevelBPETokenizer` explicitly with `save_pretrained()`, and point to the files in that directory.